# What is the difference between "depth of the trench" and "trench depth"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, word-usage

As a non-English native speaker, I don't know what is the difference between these following expressions and whether or not the first expression is correct?

The first expression:

> Then you sometimes check the **depth of the trench** when you are
>   pulverizing, dragging soil up, and then recreate your digging process.

The second expression:

> Then you sometimes check the **trench depth** when you pulverize and drag
>   the soil up, and then recreate your digging process.

Are *the depth of the trench* and *the trench depth* exactly the same? if they are different, then what is the difference here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Noun to Adjective using "of"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57649/changing-noun-to-adjective-using-of)

Comment: @ScotM It's not quite a duplicate, as the question you linked asks if there exist cases where the "adjective + of + object" structure doesn't work. I would, however, say that this question belongs in ELL.

Comment: If you are translating this to english from another language, and if I grasp your intended meaning correctly, perhaps a better phrase would be `From time to time [periodically] check the trench depth while you pulverize and drag the soil up, and adjust your digging depth as required[as appropriate/ to make it xx cm deep].`

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I removed your second question, as our format is best suited to handle a single question at a time. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for a good introduction to our standards and practices.

Comment: Also see *[“of the” vs noun adjunct](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225909)* and *[Apostrophe-“s” vs “of ”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385)*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apostrophe-“s” vs “of ”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/apostrophe-s-vs-of)

Answer (score 1):

As far as meaning goes, 'depth of the trench' and 'trench depth' are equivalent. Also for 'pulverize' vs 'pulverizing', though as the reader won't likely be reading the instructions at the time he is pulverizing, using the simple present tense is better.